# How to do isomorphic types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, type-systems

I have a file `file.ts`:

```
let a: Message = "foo"
let b: Message = "bar"
let c: Message = "baz"
```

Now I have a second file `file2.ts`

```
type Message = string

function fun(abc: Message): void { }
```

Now function `fun` will allow me to pass `string`to it, instead of `Message`, because it is only a type alias. Is there some way to isomorphic types, that is, a type that is just like another type, but there will be a strict check. So basically like Haskells `newtype`.

Comment: Check this proposal: [Support some non-structural (nominal) type matching](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/202)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [string literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) (You need to look for "String literal" in the page). Somewhat similar to an `enum`, but different, this forces a string type to contain one of a subset of specific strings:

```
type Message = "foo" | "bar" | "baz";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this (enum simulation).

```
type Message = "foo" | "bar" | "baz";
const Message = {
    Foo: 'foo' as Message,
    Bar: 'bar' as Message,
    Baz: 'baz' as Message
}
```

Then you can do:

```
function fun(abc: Message): void { 
    // you can do stuff here like 
    if (abc === Message.Bar) {
       /// ...
    }
}
fun(Message.Foo)  // ok
fun("bar")  // ok
fun("xyz")  // error
```

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the values of the **Message** type to a set of values this way.

```js
type Message = "foo" | "bar" | "baz";

function greet(message: Message) { 
    alert(message);
}

greet("foo"); // works

greet("something-else-doesn't-work"); // error
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can do something like this:

`let a:Message | string | any = "foo"`